# Do I have to leave a webapp open to get a status notification?

Tags: webapps

With the integration of webapps, do I have to leave the webpage for facebook, twitter, Google+ or any other social media (or webapp enabled site for that matter) opened to get notifications or can I fetch or configured to fetch them without having the webpage opened?

I ask since the notifications only arrive if I have the specific social media webpage opened. What I want is for them to notify me of new mail, new facebook messages or new notifications without having to have the webpage for each opened and to notify me in the messaging system here:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to leave a webapp open to get status notification.